# How do I fix the buffer overflow in build log of Travis?

Tags: javascript, travis-ci, cloud-foundry, cypress

> I execute a build in travis 
>   When it execute the deployment into Cloud Foundary i get a error message :
>   This log is too long to be displayed. Please reduce the verbosity of your build or download the raw log.
>   The travis.yml is

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- lts/*

addons:
  sonarcloud:

install:
- npm i react
- npm i react-script
- npm i -D cypress

before_script:
- npm start &

script:
- npm run cypress:run
- sonar-scanner   -Dsonar.projectKey=timerloggin   -Dsonar.organization=steinko-github   -Dsonar.sources=./src   -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io  -Dsonar.login=b0c0d7ce4ab856b9ebc10a2a6548fa7c58eecc8e

deploy:
  provider: cloudfoundry
  username: stein_korsveien@msn.com
  password: ************
  api: https://api.run.pivotal.io
  organization: stein
  space: development
  on:
    branch: master
```

> Part of the build log contains:
>
> 3.52s$ rvm $(travis_internal_ruby) --fuzzy do ruby -S gem install dpl Fetching: dpl-1.10.0.gem (100%) Successfully installed dpl-1.10.0 1
>   gem installed dpl.1 Installing deploy dependencies Fetching:
>   dpl-cloud_foundry-1.10.0.gem (100%) Successfully installed
>   dpl-cloud_foundry-1.10.0 1 gem installed dpl.2 Preparing deploy
>   LICENSE NOTICE cf Setting api endpoint to
>   https://api.run.pivotal.io... OK api endpoint:
>   https://api.run.pivotal.io api version:    2.120.0 Not logged in. Use
>   'cf login' to log in. API endpoint: https://api.run.pivotal.io
>   Authenticating... OK Targeted org stein Targeted space development
>                    API endpoint:   https://api.run.pivotal.io (API version: 2.120.0) User:           stein_korsveien@msn.com Org:
>   stein Space:          development Deploying application Pushing from
>   manifest to org stein / space development as
>   stein_korsveien@msn.com... Using manifest file
>   /home/travis/build/steinko/todo/manifest.yml Deprecation warning:
>   Specifying app manifest attributes at the top level is deprecated.
>   Found: command, disk_quota, instances, memory. Please see
>   http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#deprecated
>   for alternatives and other app manifest deprecations. This feature
>   will be removed in the future. Using manifest file
>   /home/travis/build/steinko/todo/manifest.yml Updating app toDoSteinko
>   in org stein / space development as stein_korsveien@msn.com... OK
>   Uploading toDoSteinko... Uploading app files from:
>   /home/travis/build/steinko/todo Uploading 56.9M, 56623 files Done
>   uploading OK Stopping app toDoSteinko in org stein / space development
>   as stein_korsveien@msn.com... OK Starting app toDoSteinko in org stein
>   / space development as stein_korsveien@msn.com... Downloading
>   binary_buildpack... Downloading staticfile_buildpack... Downloading
>   java_buildpack... Downloading ruby_buildpack... Downloading
>   nodejs_buildpack... Downloaded binary_buildpack Downloading
>   go_buildpack... Downloaded java_buildpack Downloading
>   python_buildpack... Downloaded staticfile_buildpack Downloading
>   php_buildpack... Downloaded nodejs_buildpack Downloading
>   dotnet_core_buildpack... Downloaded go_buildpack Downloading
>   dotnet_core_buildpack_beta... Downloaded python_buildpack Downloading
>   hwc_buildpack... Downloaded dotnet_core_buildpack_beta Downloaded
>   php_buildpack Downloaded dotnet_core_buildpack Downloaded
>   hwc_buildpack Downloaded ruby_buildpack Cell
>   f6e92664-f6c9-41d8-8359-96d91b272fd2 creating container for instance
>   babb370f-f1ee-4317-99d8-42c9eb56bda3 Cell
>   f6e92664-f6c9-41d8-8359-96d91b272fd2 successfully created container
>   for instance babb370f-f1ee-4317-99d8-42c9eb56bda3 Downloading app
>   package... Downloading build artifacts cache... Downloaded build
>   artifacts cache (222B) Downloaded app package (83.4M)
>   -----> Nodejs Buildpack version 1.6.31
>   -----> Installing binaries
>          engines.node (package.json): 8.11.4
>          engines.npm (package.json): 5.6.0
>   -----> Installing node 8.11.4
>          Copy [/tmp/buildpacks/8bb5ed140ede05dee9a86dd642cd8df7/dependencies/738985c1cf0c48ae88a5bc62c0aab3dc/node-8.11.4-linux-x64-cflinuxfs2-f03d0cbe.tgz]
>          npm 5.6.0 already installed with node
>   -----> Installing yarn 1.9.4
>          Copy [/tmp/buildpacks/8bb5ed140ede05dee9a86dd642cd8df7/dependencies/2d10153dc84bbc49dedac3162db062ff/yarn-v1.9.4-7667eb71.tar.gz]
>          Installed yarn 1.9.4
>   -----> Creating runtime environment
>          NODE_ENV=production
>          NODE_HOME=/tmp/contents864275922/deps/0/node
>          NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
>          NODE_VERBOSE=false
>          NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
>          NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
>   -----> Building dependencies
>          Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
>          Rebuilding any native modules
>
> > uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /tmp/app/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> >     node lib/post_install.js
> >     cypress@3.1.0 postinstall /tmp/app/node_modules/cypress
> >     node index.js --exec install Installing Cypress (version: 3.1.0) [14:56:38]  Downloading Cypress     [started] [14:56:39]  Downloading
> >     Cypress      0% 0s [title changed] [14:56:39]  Downloading Cypress
> >     2% 5s [title changed] [14:56:39]  Downloading Cypress      3% 7s
> >     [title changed] [14:56:39]  Downloading Cypress      3% 10s [title
> >     changed] [14:56:39]  Downloading Cypress      5% 8s [title changed]
>
> How do I reduce the reduce the verbosity?